# How can I tell the rarity of the item?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

There are a lot of items in the game, but how can I tell what is valuable/rare and what is not?

The up/down thumbs seem very subjective, how does it decide that 3% protection is more valuable than 6% resistance or +1 to a skill?

Comment: It also seems to rate upgrade slots fairly highly as items that are  worse than what i am using but have upgrade slots get a thumbs up on occasion.

Comment: Because the 3% protection might have 12 upgrade slots while the 6% resistance only has 1 or 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to their wiki, the adjectives of an item will tell you the maximum number or attribute points the item can have. A Pristine Godly item will be best possible combination for armor. The page has a really nice chart for you to see.

http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Armor